# How to put text on two sides of an image responsively?

Tags: html, css, frontend, responsive

It's very simple. I just need to put two lines of text on either side of an image which is centered on my landing page. I don't know how to make it responsive except for using `position: absolute`. How can I do this without having to use `position: absolute`.

I tried using flexbox but it seems like it won't let me adjust the position of my text freely as the items are literally adjacent to each other.

Here's the code employing flexbox:

```
<div class="overall">
  <div class="hi">
    <p>OH <br>GOSH <br> HI!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="human-container">
    <img src="img/landing page human.svg" onmouseover="this.src='img/landing page human 2.svg'"
      onmouseout="this.src='img/landing page human.svg'">
  </div>
  <div class="my-name">
    <p>MY<br> NAME<br> IS <span class="Ray">Ray</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some code and describe what didn't work for you. Produce a minimal, working example where we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I just edited my post. I can't add the Css part in because I still can't figure out how to make this work with flexbox...

Comment: @hùng nguyễn mạnh At least try to represent the way you want it to be by some image or scetch, exactly how you want it to be

Comment: I am so sorry for not having been transparent :( I have an image that's placed in the center of my first section of my landing page and named "human-container". On either side of the image, I just want the line "Hi" on the left side and "My name is Ray" on the right side :( Is it any better?? This is literally my first time asking on this thread so I'm still not good at how I describe what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

I would go simply by following these steps:
 - Add *"float: left;"* to the following classes: **".overall", ".hi", ".human-container"** and **".my-name"**.
 - Add an **id(#)** to the *img* and give-it a *float:left;* and a *width:100%;* too.
 - Give to class **".hi"** a *width: 5%;*
 - Give to class **"human-container"** a *width:90%;*
 - Give to class **"my-name"** a *width:5%*.
 This should do it. 
:D

Comment: Oh so I think it's my bad for not describing it right. So I want the "hi" on the left and the "my name is Ray" on the right of the image and when I downsize the screen, they are all in one line...

Comment: You're welcome man! :D
(care to pick my answer as "right" below the upvoting arrows? It would mean a lot to me - Thanks!)